# string last digits after underscroll

Tags: php, regex

I have a few strings like this

```
take_a quizz_0
go_shop_1
now_is_time_to_ping_9
great_1
```

etc etc.

I have a need to truncate the number and under scroll at the end of the string

```
 $new string = substr($k, 0, -2);
```

works great as long as I have single digit numbers. What can I do to improve it so that it doesnt matter how many digits are there, it will alway give me the string with without the number and underscroll at the end.

so in other words I will get

```
take_a quizz
go_shop
now_is_time_to_ping
great
```

Comment: [Good old pure php](https://eval.in/143995)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `preg_replace`:

```
$str = preg_replace('/_[0-9]+$/', '', $str);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
    echo implode('_', explode('_', $k, -1));
```

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: I tested it, try too. :)

Comment: You are right, I didn't know the behavior of explode with a negative limit parameter.